# Android Things - Front facing camera on IMX7d

Tags: camera, android-things

I am currently developing an Android Things application on an IMX7d developer board and need to figure out how to get the default camera, which is configured as BACK, to be a FRONT facing one, with correct orientation.  This application will make heavy use of the camera, for example with face recognition.

I've noticed with other android phones you can edit /etc/nvcamera.conf to do this, but the Android things OS image I have doesn't seem to have that file.  Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: As the device builder, you can mount the camera module in any orientation you like. I'm wondering if you could clarify why your code needs the camera to report a specific direction?

Comment: It's facing in the front, however the operating system has it as a "back" camera; this causes it to automatically reverse everything.  This is a huge problem if you're giving instructions on the screen for the user to move his face a certain way.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the feedback. We don't expose a method for configuring this today, but I will forward this feedback to the engineering team.